# Why doesn't the following key mapping work in which-key? (Vim)

Tags: vim

```
let g:which_key_map['H'] = [' :call CompileRunGcc()', 'compile' ]


func! CompileRunGcc()
exec "w"
if &filetype == 'c'
exec "!gcc % -o %<"
exec "!time ./%<"
elseif &filetype == 'cpp'
exec "!g++ % -o %<"
exec "!time ./%<"
elseif &filetype == 'java'
exec "!javac %"
exec "!time java -cp %:p:h %:t:r"
elseif &filetype == 'sh'
exec "!time bash %"
elseif &filetype == 'python'
exec "!time python2.7 %"
elseif &filetype == 'html'
exec "!firefox % &"
elseif &filetype == 'go'
exec "!go build %<"
exec "!time go run %"
elseif &filetype == 'mkd'
exec "!~/.vim/markdown.pl % > %.html &"
exec "!firefox %.html &"
endif
endfunc
```

This is all in my which-key.vim file and I know that the function works, but when I try it for some file it doesn't work. Do I maybe have to put the function somewhere else?

Comment: 1. There is no mapping in your question. 2. Compilation is usually done with `:help :make`, `:help 'makeprg'`, `:help compiler`, etc. 3. The issue tracker for that plugin is [this way](https://github.com/liuchengxu/vim-which-key/issues)`.

Comment: @romainl isn't the let g: ... a key mapping? How would I do the above correctly?

Comment: The `g:` thing is some convoluted abstraction exposed by a third-party plugin. That's not how mappings are done. If you are interested in how to do it with vanilla Vim, feel free to ask a separate question (ideally after searching for similar ones). If not, the plugin's issue tracker is your best bet.

Comment: As for "doing it correctly", you would define `:help 'makeprg'` for each of those filetypes in its corresponding ftplugin and create a single mapping for `:make<CR>` in your `vimrc`.